# How to know the latest version of source code used for an executable?

Tags: c, unix, executable, binaryfiles

I have a list of binaries and different versions of the source codes. How am I supposed to know which version of the source code has been used for a particular binary executable?

Comment: Have you tried `strings <executable_file>` then checking the content of the stdout? This will allow you to have a look at the strings in the binary file, and you might even get the whole information you need! Also try readelf -h <executable_file> to have information about the ELF of your exe however you will not have more information about your version number

Comment: Are you asking about how to find out for code without any mechanisms to support your goal? In that case the answer is "Be a Sherlock, find the difference in the code and look for a matching difference in the binary." In the other case, please show what the files contain as mechanisms. Or are you asking about how to plan for this situation in the future? I.e. you ask for proposals how to handle this. Note that the comment and the answer are different in these aspects. So your question is unclear without further explanation.

Answer (score 3):

This is a question about software version management. It's your decision how you want to do this. You can put a version information in the code, e.g. in a string or variable, or to a resource container that might be available in a Windows executable.

A good approach is to use a version control system (e.g. git) and add a tag to repository with the version number you have put to the code.

Answer (score 0):

one possible method:

near the top of each source file, declare a 'const' string that contains the current configuration management file version number.

Later when checking, look in the .const section of the executable.